# CSS variables are undefined when using with ::-webkit-scrollbar

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, scrollbar

Please check out this [codepen example](https://codepen.io/hemanthvj-the-looper/pen/zYJwjpN)

```
body {
  width: 110000px;
  height: 110000px;
  background-color: black;
}

:root {
   --scrollBarWidth: 5px;
  --scrollBarHeight: 5px;
  --scrollBarWidthWide: 8px;
  --scrollBarHeightWide: 8px;
  --scrollBarThumbColor: red;
  --scrollBarTrackColor: blue;
  --scrollBarBorderRadius: 5px;
  --scrollBarThumbColorHover: red;
  --scrollBarWidthFirefox: thin;
}

  body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: var(--scrollBarHeight);
    width: var(--scrollBarWidth);
  }
```

If you inspect it, you will see that the css variables are shown as "not defined", but the styling is working fine.

Context:
I am using create-react-app to create a web-app and styling the scrollbar using ::-webkit-scrollbar and css variables just like in the above codepen.
The css variables are shown as "undefined" but styling is correctly applied work on (This is for localhost development mode)
But when i build and deploy it, they no longer work.

I would expect them to be not shown as undefined and work when i build and deploy.

Comment: You have casing discrepancies (i.e. `--scrollBar` versus `--scrollbar`). Both CSS and JS are case-sensitive, and you'd need to ensure consistency.

Comment: @BumhanYu Oh sorry made a mistake while copying to codepen. Even if i correct it inspect still shows it as undefined.